# Do I need a cross domain policy?

Tags: c#, apache-flex, security, permissions, cross-domain-policy

I'm working with a flex (3.5) application with a swf embedded in a php page which is communicating with a C# asp.net website, when I ran my project in debug mode through Visual Studio's 2008 and the php webpage on my own machine everything worked fine. I then moved everything to a web-server and now it only intermittently works producing the following error in the flash logs when it doesn't work:

"Error: Request for resource at /c#website by requestor from /php-webpage/swf-file is denied due to lack of policy file permissions."

I've done a lot of reading around policy files and do understand their purpose but what I don't understand is surely if my php web page and C# project are hosted on the same server then I don't need a policy file because I'm not communicating across domains - I'm using the same server?

Am I missing something here or have simply misunderstood policy files? Why do the flash logs complain about the policy file permissions if they're not necessary?

Comment: They're on the same server, but are they on the same domain? Note that `php.mydomain.com` and `csharp.mydomain.com` are not the same domain.

Comment: If your error were a cross domain issue; it is likely it would fail every time; not only intermittently.

Comment: RIAstar: The C# project and php website have different virtual directories under the Default Web Site in IIS

Comment: www.Flextras.com: I know the intermittent nature of this doesn't make any sense. I've actually also tried putting a cross-domain policy in but it still only works sometimes and produces the same error message in the flash logs

Comment: Turn on policy file logging and let us know what it says… http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec4.html

Comment: I have setup my policies in exactly the same way as this: [link](http://www.davidturvey.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/using-a-custom-crossdomain-xml-policy-file-with-flex-34/) and enabled policy file logging as you asked. I get messages beginning "OK" for root level SWF loaded, Policy file accepted: server root, Policy file accepted: custom location, Searching for <allow-access-from> in policy files... and then another "OK" message for Policy file accepted: server root followed by an Error row with the exactly the same message as the flash logs

Comment: Just to be clear I've used "all" in the permitted-cross-domain-policies property of the site-control tag in the master policy file unlike the link I provided above

Answer (score 0):

@user1456312, I have no knowledge about C# server, but maybe I can give you some idea to solve it.

In the debug mode, there is no security restriction, so there is no problem.

Can you get the crossdomain.xml file directly when you type the url address in the browser?

Where do you place the crossdomain file and what is your url address to access your program?

You may try the following crossdomain for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM “/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd”>
<cross-domain-policy> 
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/> 
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This file is not for production because it means no restriction at all

You can use `Security.loadPolicyFile(url)` to load a crossdomain.xml file from an alternate location on the server, when it is necessary.

Comment: michael: I can get both crossdomain files directly and have one in the server root folder (Inenpub\wwwroot) with the same site-control tag as your crossdomain above and another in the C# website folder with the same allow-access-from domain tag as yours (without the secure property and allow-http-request-headers because they cause errors) with Security.loadPolicyFile(url) linking to it

Comment: user1456312, have you tried using the Fiddler to do the packet trace?

Comment: I've used wireshark and can see the packets travelling and the policy logs show the policy being successfully read so I don't think it's a networking issue